# Django. Add selection flags each list item

Tags: django, django-admin

Good day! I have the object list in admins's cabinet, I must add the flag in front of each item to select (True / False), for example, on this picture

[image: SearchTerm Admin]

How do I make this with standard methods of Django?

In my case, i have page, for example
[image: SearchTerm Admin]

I must create checkbox for multichoice and action

Comment: The Django admin *already* has that.

Comment: No, in my case, i have objects list on page, but haven't checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add at least one action. Standard "delete_selected" apparently removed.

```
class FakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['fake_action']

    def fake_action(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update()
```